# finding the time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to understand the subtle difference in the complexity of 
each of the examples below.

### Example A

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      sum++;
```

**My Analysis:**

The first for loop goes for lg n times.
The inner loop is independent of outer loop and executes N times every time outer loop executes.

So the complexity must be:
n+n+n... lg n times

Therefore the complexity is `n lg n`.

Is this correct?

### Example B

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i *= 2)
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
      sum++;
```

**My Analysis:**

The first for loop goes for lg n times.
The inner loop execution depends on outer loop.

So how do I calculate the complexity when no of times inner loop executes depends on outer loop?

### Example C

```
int sum = 0;
for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2)
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      sum++;
```

I think example C and example B must have same complexity because no of times the inner loop executes depends on outer loop.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In examples B and C, the inner loop executes `1 + 2 + ... + n/2 + n` times. There happen to be `lg n` terms in this sequence, and that does mean that `int i = 0` executes `lg n` times, however the sum for the statement(s) in the inner loop is `2n`. So we get `O(n + lg n) = O(n)`

Comment: can you explain how the sum is 2n ?

Comment: `1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ... = 2`.  In general see [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)

Answer (score 1):

(a) Your analysis is correct

(b) The outer loop goes log(N) times. The inner loop goes in the sequence `1, 2, 4, 8, ...` for log(N) times which is a geometric series and is equal to `(approx) O(2^log(N))` or twice the amount of the highest multiple.

E.g. : `1 + 2 + 4 = (approx)2*4`, `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = (approx)2*8`.

Hence the total complexity is `O(2^log(N)) = O(N)`

(c) This is same as (b) in reverse order

Comment: It would be more correct to say that's the sum of a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), also leading you to O(2^log n) (which I believe is O(n)).

Comment: 2^log(N) is equal to N; the complexity is O(n)

Comment: @Dukeling I have a little grey area on how the O(2^logn) gets there. In the part C, the inner loop runs for log(n) times and the outer loop runs for log(n) times. So it should be log(n) * log(n) ==> (log(n))^2 and then how did it become 2^log(N) ??

Comment: @AchalaYasasPiyarathna The number of times the inner loop runs is dependent on the outer loop, you can't just directly say it's `log N`. You directly get to `O(2^log N)` from `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + N` (which is the number of times the inner loop actually runs) thanks to the formula for [geometric series sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).

Answer (score -1):

Fine Time complexity

```
I=1;
K=1;
While(k<n)
{
    Stmt;
    K=k+i;
    I++;
}
```